# Enumerate a "map" variable

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have the following "map" variables:

```
permutation[100]=-2;
permutation[3]=-1;
permutation[19]=0;
permutation[-20]=1;
```

Is there a way to enumerate all of the values?
I don't care about enumeration order.
I mean something like this (not working code):

```
Do[i+=3,{i,permutation}]
```

I tell them "map" variables inspired from C++. What is the correct name for them, to found better search results?

Comment: permutation[100] = -2;
permutation[3] = -1;
permutation[19] = 0;
permutation[-20] = 1;
DownValues[permutation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you have done is basically define a function of discrete values.  If you maintain a list of the values you can do this:

```
permutation[100] = -2;
permutation[3] = -1;
permutation[19] = 0;
permutation[-20] = 1;
vals = {100, 3, 19, -20}
```

use like this:

```
f /@ permutation /@ vals  -> {f[-2], f[-1], f[0], f[1]}
```

or in a loop..

```
Do[ Print[permutation[vals[[i]]]], {i, Length[vals]}]
```

there are probably better ways to define your data in the first place..

here is a sometimes useful trick  (only works for posative args though)

```
permutation = SparseArray[{}, {200}, Null]
permutation[[100]] = -2;
permutation[[3]] = -1;
permutation[[19]] = 0;
f /@ Select[ permutation, ! (TrueQ[# == Null]) &]

out: {f[-1], f[0], f[-2]}
```

simplest though is to just make permutation a list:

```
permutation={}
AppendTo[permutation,{100,2}]
AppendTo[permutation,{3,-1}]
```

then do

```
 f[#[[2]]]& /@ permutation -> {f[2],f[-1]}
```

Comment: oops, just noticed you want to change the value in the loop. All of the above can do that with a bit of tweaking..

Answer (score 2):

This is "Meta Mathematica"
Definitions for a variable or a functions are stored internally and can be extracted using DownValues[]
so, if you want the set of "input values" for which permutation is defined use

```
Cases[DownValues[permutation], permutation[x_] :> x, \[Infinity]]
```

resulting with

```
{-20, 3, 19, 100}
```

yehuda